# What was xhbin?

Tags: directory-structure, history

I've [googled](http://google.com/search?q=xhbin+unix), [searched Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=xhbin), and... well, there's not really much else I *can* do, is there?

I was browsing [some quines in various shell languages](http://www.nyx.net/~gthompso/self_sh.txt), and I came upon the following shebang:

```
#!/xhbin/bash
```

A lot of [old](https://www.student.cs.uwaterloo.ca/~cs132/Resources/ChangeShell.html) [websites](http://uw.cs.cs241.narkive.com/qjRblzio/changing-your-shell) (seem to) talk about it like we talk about `/bin` today, but on the other hand, a lot of the [aforementioned shell quines](http://www.nyx.net/~gthompso/self_sh.txt) use `/bin/bash`.

What on *earth* was `xhbin`? I thought it was `/bin` [all the way <s>down</s> back](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtles_all_the_way_down) to like, 1970?

Comment: The two links you posted are both from University of Waterloo.  Looks like they had their own special setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Mikel is right](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/275380/what-was-xhbin#comment478477_275380). From [this post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/uw.cs.cs246/Iw8h9q8SLmQ/gKmCqbM6gfsJ) on Google Groups' group for CS246 at the University of Waterloo:

> Don't let the /xhbin part spook you.  This is a peculiarity of the
>   MFCF/CSCF  environment.  I don't know all of the details, but some
>   time ago MFCF developed  a program called xhier to make it easier to
>   distribute software to a large  number of machines.  The xh in xhbin
>   just means that your shell has been  changed to an instance of the
>   shell that is under xhier's control.  It's  still bash.

MFCF and CSCF are, respectively, the Math Faculty Computing Facility and Computer Science Computing Facility.